# Have a conditional for which image to display in SceneBuilder

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to find a way to have it so a certain scene is displayed the same but a certain outside variable will influence which image is displayed. Is there a way to do this or should I just make multiple scenes with the different images in them?

Comment: Use a controller and implement the logic for modifying the `ImageView.image` property there...

Comment: You could use something like this: `imageView.imageProperty().bind(Bindings.when(influencingBooleanProperty)).then(imageA).otherwise(imageB)`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not want to make multiple scenes. One of the major concepts of JavaFX (and Java in general as well as other object-oriented programming languages) is **DRY** coding: **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself.

Reuse as much code as you can at all times. So you should only create one Scene, and update it's UI elements as needed.

---

Here is a very simple example that uses `FXML` to build a `Scene` with a single `Label` being displayed. Note that a `Label` is what is known as a `Node` and a `Node` can actually be any visual element, whether it's a `Label` or an image or any other item that is displayed on screen.

So while this example uses a `Label`, the concept is identical when using an image instead.

---

> **Main.java**:

*This class is used simply to load our FXML file and start the application.*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Layout.fxml"));

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

> **Layout.fxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      alignment="CENTER"
      spacing="10"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="drySample.LayoutController"
      prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">

    <!--    Let's display a simple Label and Button -->
    <Label fx:id="label" text="This is the initial text!"/>
    <Button fx:id="button" text="Change Text"/>

</VBox>
```

> **LayoutController.java**:

*A "controller" is a term used to describe the class that contains the logic used to define how the UI elements in an FXML file will behave.*

*Here, we simply want our `Button` to change an existing UI element (the text displayed in the `Label` in this case.*

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class LayoutController {

    // By using the @FXML annotation, we tell JavaFX that these nodes are already defined in the FXML file this 
    // controller ... controls.
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Now we have access to both our label and button that are defined in our FXML scene
        // Let's set the action of the button to change the text of the Label
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            // These types of actions can also be used to change an image or a myriad of other things.
            label.setText("You changed the text!");
        });

    }
}
```

---

If you were to run this application, you'll see the following interface:

[image: screenshot]

After clicking the `Change Text` button, the text above it will be changed to "You changed the text!"

---

So in this way, you can design your interface layout to your exact needs, and update what information is displayed within that layout.